# PHP constructor generates infinite loop when call method inside method

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, infinite-loop

I have a constructor in Laravel Eloquent Model. When I instantiate the Model I've got an infinite loop when the method that constructor calls call another method.

```
class ChessboardCell extends Model
{
    //...

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //...

        $this->putPieces('pawn', 'black', $blackPawns);

        //...
    }

    private function putPieces($piece, $player, $piecesArray)
    {
        //...

        if ($piece == 'pawn') {
            for ($file = 'a'; $file <= 'h'; $file++) {
                $pawnPiece = array_shift($piecesArray);
                $this->putPieceOnBoard($file, $rank, $pawnPiece);
            }
        }

        //...
    }

    public function putPieceOnBoard($file, $rank, $piece)
    {
        $chessboardCell = ChessboardCell::where('file', $file)
            ->where('rank', $rank)
            ->first();

        if (is_null($chessboardCell)) {
            // Gera excessão: não pegou a célula
        }
        $chessboardCell->current_piece = $piece->id;

        $chessboardCell->save();
    }

}
```

After calling `$this->putPieceOnBoard` inside `putPieces function` gets infinite loop.

What happens here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all notice that this piece of code calls you constructor:

```
    $chessboardCell = ChessboardCell::where('file', $file)
        ->where('rank', $rank)
        ->first();
```

Then notice that you are calling `putPieces()` from the `__constructor()` and the `__constructor()` is called by the `putPieceOnBoard()` which is called by `putPieces()` and so on and so forth.

So the solution in this case is the holy principle of Single Responsibility ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)), you remove the `putPieces()` from the constructor and call it separately instead.

For more about the software design principles please check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Answer (score 0):

In constructor You use `$blackPawns` variable. But where it come from ?
Maybe You should change you code like this

```
public function __construct($blackPawns)
{
    parent::__construct();

    //...

    $this->putPieces('pawn', 'black', $blackPawns);

    //...
}
```

Comment: `$blackPawns refers an array of objects declared above `putPieces` call.

Comment: Can you show where and  how you declared $blackPawns array ?

Comment: In fact, `$blackPawns` is a variable that receives an array returned by a function that call other Eloquent model method to retrieve some objects. I expressed myself unclear. I think is not necessary to update the question to include more lines of code, because answer of @Ahmad clarified the issue.